# Pairing function for NxN->N for unordered tuple

Tags: number-theory

For a program I'm writing - I want to check if a number x is in a set of numbers A={a_1, ..., a_n}.

I've been wanting to combine the numbers into one, using a method like Cantor pairing and then quickly check if the number is a member somehow.

Obviously I can do it with - 2^a_1*3^a_2*5^a_3*... - but that will generate too large numbers + have to factor the number and then check - which is O(n) operation.

I was hoping for some nice way to achieve this - basically to combine n numbers to one, where order doesn't matter - just like a search in a set.

Found this, but not sure this can help me: https://gist.github.com/ma11hew28/9457506

thx

Comment: So, you have a number of sets with fixed number of elements (numbers), and you want a single-number representation for any such set?

Comment: I want a quick way to encode n numbers and check if a certain number in that list. Just existence.

Comment: One possibility is to instead of raising primes to the power, take $a_n$-th prime a multiply all such primes together. Not saying its optimal, but certainly you won't explode in size that quickly and no two n-tuples will have the same "number code"

Comment: Finding the a_n-th prime is kinda hard :(
My numbers are kinda big...

I was hoping for a more compact solution like Cantor's pairing - but one that the order is irrelevant

Comment: @TStancek It comes close to optimal, because the $n$th prime is not much bigger (number of bits) than $n$, and you can check for a number to be in the set easily: just try to divide by the $n$th prime.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's low quality and apparently abandoned.